# Пронумеровать список

Tags: jquery

Есть список и нужно его пронумеровать. Под пронумеровать подразумевается добавление классов: во 2 уровне `ul`, например, `сlass_2`, в 3 уровне `ul` - `сlass_3`.
Должно получится что-то типа такого.

Предполагаю, решение кроется в jQuery, но точно не знаю как сделать.

```
<ul  class="class_1">
   <li>
      <ul class="class_2">
         <li></li>
         <li>
            <ul class="class_3">
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <ul class="class_2">
         <li></li>
         <li>
            <ul class="class_3">
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <ul class="class_3">
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <ul class="class_3">
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так

```js
function setClass(AList) {
  var level = AList.data('level');
  if (level)
    return level;
  var parent = $(AList.parent().closest('ul'));
  if (parent.length)
    var level = setClass(parent) + 1;
  else
    var level = 1;
  AList.addClass('class_' + level).data({level: level});
  return level;
}

$('ul:not(:has(ul))').each(function() {
  setClass($(this));
});
```

```css
.class_1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.class_2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.class_3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li>
            <ul>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li>
            <ul>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <ul>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <ul>
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Идея:

- вначале выбираем все списки, которые не имеют дочерних списков `$('ul:not(:has(ul))')`.
- Затем для каждого из этих списков рекурсивно ищем родительский, чтобы узнать на каком уровне мы находимся
- все вычисленные уровни сохраняем, чтобы не вычислять для одного и того же элемента дважды

Comment: Отлично все, просто супер. Я просто мыслил что как то так надо.. но как все делать и организовать не знал.

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно просто пробежаться по всем первым потомкам каждого ul-a, предварительно установив класс для первого ul-a.

https://jsfiddle.net/lermon333/ep9wh2v9/

```
var index = 1;
var first = $('ul').first();
first.addClass(index + "_class");
index += 1;
setClass(first, index);

function setClass(parent, index) {
  firstUlChilds = parent.find(">li>ul");
  firstUlChilds.addClass(index + "_class");
  index += 1;
  if (firstUlChilds.length) {
    firstUlChilds.each(function(i, el){
      setClass($(el), index);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: А если не выполнится условие `>li>ul` (например - `>li>div>ul`) то поплакать

Comment: А если нужно написать свой язык гиперразметки?... Конкретный вопрос - конкретный ответ.

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov прав, у меня есть и дивы.. Все равно метод рабоатает.. сохранил его как для 1 из варианта